# How to test a Spring Boot application that requires an eventlistener which is attached to SpringApplicationBuilder?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

In a Spring Boot application, an `EventListener` is registered with the `SpringApplicationBuilder`, which listens for an `ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent` and then prepares a specific class, which is required during the ongoing initialization of the application context.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
                .listeners(EnvironmentPreparedListener.INSTANCE)
                .run(args);
}
```

It is absolutely necessary that the ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent is thrown so that the listener can catch it and prepare variables, which are then required, among other things, for the initialization of e.g. the `SecurityFilterChain`s.

In the following `SpringBootTest`, however, the Spring application is not started via the main method and thus the listener is not registered and therefore the listener cannot prepare this specific class which is required for the correct initialization of the application context:

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class CommonAuthenticationTest {

    @Autowired WebApplicationContext context;
    MockMvc mvc;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity())
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    void page_login_is_authorized_for_anonymous() throws Exception {
        MvcResult result = mvc
                .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                        .get("/login")
                        .with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.anonymous()))

                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andReturn();
    }
}
```

The result is then logically a `BeanCreationException` (e.g. for SecurityFilterChain).

### My question now is:

Is it somehow possible to modify the `WebApplicationContext` so that `MockMvc` runs the SpringBootTest successfully?
Maybe it is possible to tell the SpringBootTest to start with a registered EnvironmentPreparedListener, just as the application starts normally?

Many thanks for any help

Comment: (if I get all right): Wouldn't `@Bean EventListener myListener(){return EnvironmentPreparedListener.INSTANCE;}` have the same effect as the main method (but test friendlier)? (Or is it "too late for this type of event" ..since spring( boot) normally "picks up" all `EventListener` *beans*.)

Comment: You are right, this would be too late. It's one of the Spring Boots starting events, in particular, the `ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent` is the second event published by Spring Boot still before the context is build. And that is why I need this Event/Listener combination: to prepare things BEFORE Spring Boot begins to build its application context.

Comment: Spring boot >= 3? (->`SpringBootTest#useMainMethod`!), otherwise...

Comment: @xerx593: works, perfect, thanks !!! Maybe you wanna write an aswer I can confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Spring Boot 3, we can use:

```
@SpringBootTest(useMainMethod = SpringBootTest.UseMainMethod.ALWAYS)
```

..for such "constructs". ([javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html#useMainMethod()))

Before 3:

- avoid (the need for) such heavy intervention in spring (boot) life cycle
- ..depends on the specific scenario (need to work around:)